# Turning this string in modwrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

pre_config_step_2.php?type=Grocery&count=2

to

/pre_config_step_2/Grocery/2

do i need to change the htaccess in the root directory and if so what do i change it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule   ^pre_config_step_2/(\w+)/(\d+)$ pre_config_step_2.php?type=$1&count=$2
</IfModule>
```

That would consider accessing `/pre_config_step_2/Grocery/2` as if requesting `pre_config_step_2.php?type=Grocery&count=2`.

Comment: here is the link

http://posnation.com/pre_config/pre_config_step_2/Grocery/1

and its not working

Comment: Where did you put the .htaccess file? Also, are you sure you have a working mod_rewrite support? (To check, change `RewriteEngine` into `RewriteEngineBlabla` and see if it issues a `500 internal server error`)

Comment: There seems to be an .httaccess file that is filled up with lots of stuff in the root of public_html folder and the file has 

here is an example of whats in there now

RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

# Ban robots from the secure site

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ /robots_ssl.txt [L]
RewriteRule   ^pre_config_step_2/(\w+)/(\d+)$ pre_config_step_2.php?type=$1&count=$2

# force miva https login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

Comment: the `.htaccess` file should be in the `public_html/pre_config/` folder, not the `public_html/` root. Try with that.

Comment: ok so the file is now in the right place and i changed it to RewriteEngineBlabla and look at the link now....but when i change it back to the way i originally had it nothing

http://posnation.com/pre_config/pre_config_step_2/Grocery/2

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase   /pre_config` line after `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: that worked thanks

RewriteRule ^step2/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /pre_config/pre_config_step_2.php?type=$1&count=$2

Comment: but now my stylesheets are all off

Comment: yes thanks for all your help on that...so the css path should be absolute...

what do you mean by new / slashes in the url,

Comment: I suggest asking a new question, it's more structured and will help other people looking for the same info. Put a new question about relative and absolute urls and how relative paths break on url rewriting.